# Does sails-arangodb support waterline index?

Tags: waterline, arangodb

I've tried to set up an index on a field using the index:true attribute but it doesn't seem to have any effect.  Is this something on the TODO list or am I missing something?

Secondly, is there a way to specify the edge collections as models?  Currently, I'm hooking sails bootstrap.js to create edges and insert index fields but it would be nice to avoid that.

Comment: We haven't been doing much with sails, so we can't comment on this; It seems the author did neither in the recent past: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/graphs/code-frequency are you shure your choice of technology is good? We maintain [arangojs](https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs) which is what we can provide good feedback on.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to ask the author directly. I've been using arangojs for almost everything anyway because sails-arangodb doesn't have many features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a number of features missing from this package. The sails-arangodb package is a work in progress and needs some assistance and TLC to finish.